# How to install non-standard build target output file using CMake?

Tags: cmake, emscripten, webassembly

I have a CMake library target that outputs a foo.js and foo.wasm file in the build directory. However, when I install() the target, only foo.js appears in the install directory. How can I get CMake to also install foo.wasm? I'm using the Emscripten toolchain to generate WebAssembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install foo.wasm like this:

```
install(FILES foo.wasm DESTINATION {your-destination})
```

Comment: Ended up using: install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo.wasm DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})